# Wrong Display Converting Array to XML Result in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have trouble to display xml in php. before it, i converted an array code to xml.
i got array result from `oci_fetch_array`

```
while ($data = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_BOTH)) {
        $parent = $data['PARENT'];
        if($data['PARENT'] == 0) {
            $idx++;
            $idx2 = 0;
            $product[$idx]['text'] = $data['NAME'];
            $product[$idx]['cls'] = "folder"; 
        } else {
            $product[$idx]['children'][$idx2]['id'] = $data['ID'];
            $product[$idx]['children'][$idx2]['name'] = $data['NAME'];
            $product[$idx]['children'][$idx2]['code'] = $data['CODE'];
            $idx2++;
        }
    }
```

And this is the array result:

```
Array
(
    [-1] => Array
        (
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [name] => SPEEDY 384 KB
                            [code] => SPEEDY_384KB
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 7
                            [name] => SPEEDY 2 MB
                            [code] => SPEEDY_2MB
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

then i used php code to convert it into xml, this is the code:

```
$product2=array($product);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<services/>");
array_walk_recursive($product2, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
$string=$xml->asXML();
echo '<pre>', htmlentities($string), '</pre>';
```

yes, i got result but it's not what i hope. this is the result...

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <services>
        <4>id</4>
        <SPEEDY YOO>name</SPEEDY YOO>
        <SPEEDY_LOO>code</SPEEDY_LOO>
        <7>id</7>
        <2 MB>name</ 2 MB>
        <U2MB>code</U2MB>
    </services>
```

the result that i want is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <services>
        <id>4</id>
        <name>SPEEDY YOO</name>
        <code>SPEEDY_LOO</code>
        <id>7</id>
        <name>2 MB</name >
        <code>U2MB</code>
    </services>
```

how can i get the right one? help me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use array_flip() before using SimpleXMLElement because it uses the array index as values and the array values as tag names.

presuming that $product contains your data:

```
$product2=array(array_flip($product));
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<services/>");
array_walk_recursive($product2, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
$string=$xml->asXML();
echo '<pre>', htmlentities($string), '</pre>';
```

Comment: could you give me an example? @DanieleD ? Cause i try with '$product2=array($product);
$products=array_flip($product2);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<services/>");
array_walk_recursive($products, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
$string=$xml->asXML();
echo '<pre>', htmlentities($string), '</pre>';'

Comment: I added one, presuming that $product is your array.

Comment: ok, i've tried, but it show '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<services/>' only, there's no data... @DanieleD

Comment: Can you please tell me the content of $product and $product2 by print_r() ?

Comment: the result of print_r() is the array result.. @DanieleD

Comment: I suggest using an anonymous function around SimpleXMLElement::addChild(). This would allow validation for the tag names, too. *btw* Here are several formats (Json as XML) for different uses: **Badgerfish** (about what your currently using), Rayfish, JsonML, JsonX, ... with libraries generating them.

Comment: i fixed it by add 'multiArrayFlip()' function.. you gave me the clue @DanieleD . thanks a lot